# How to optimize the jQuery code for click()

Tags: jquery

How could i optimize the following jQuery Code?

```
var $open = $('#open'),
        $panel = $('div#panel'),
        $close = $('#close'),
        $switch = $('#toggle');
$open.click(function(){
    $panel.slideDown('slow');
});
$close.click(function(){
    $panel.slideUp('slow');
});
$switch.children('p').click(function(){
    $switch.children('p').toggle();
});
$close.css({'display':'none'});
```

I think there is a much better way to write this.

This is the HTML-Code it belongs to.

```
<div class="tab">
  <ul class="login">
    <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li id="toggle">
      {if $smarty.session.customer_id}
      <a id="open" class="open" href="{$logoff}" title="{#link_logoff#}">{#link_logoff#}</a>{else}<p id="open" class="open">{#link_login#}</p>
      {/if}
      <p id="close" class="close">Schließen</p>         
    </li>
    <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: "I think there is a much better way to write this." - Not without seeing the HTML there isn't.

Comment: I've added the missing HTML-Code

Comment: Post your generated `HTML` code what browser sees, not smarty stuff.

Comment: Be careful not to optimize just for the sake of optimization. [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write it like this:

```
    var $open = $('#open'),
        $panel = $('div#panel'),
        $close = $('#close')

    $open.click(function(){
        $panel.slideDown('slow');
    });

    $close.click(function(){
        $panel.slideUp('slow');
    });

    $('#toggle p').click(function(){
        $('#toggle p').toggle();
    });

    $close.hide()
```

Not too different, i don't know what is giving you problems and what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Isn't it possible to write the code something like this $('#book').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      }); instead of starting new with every element

Comment: the difference of `toggle()` and fadeIn is the fading part, toggle() uses show/hide instead of fadeIn/Out, i think you can do effects with it too, check on jQuery's site.